# border image not showing in safari

Tags: html, safari, css

border-image not showing up in Safari or on tablet and mobile devices.  It's fine in FF, IE, Chrome and Opera.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 ctas" id="togglelinks">
    <div class="rooms">
        <img src="images/bedroom1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <h6>Room 1</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</p>
        <p><a class="btn togglee" target="one">MORE INFORMATION</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.rooms {
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-image: url("../images/paint-blk.png") fill 21 repeat;
}
```

A little more information: I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.3.  The page is validating.  In FireBug the borders are being brought through, colour, padding, but not the image.

Answer (score 21):

I found this post while looking for a solution for the same problem with Safari 10.0. I was able to find a solution and wanted to share it in case somebody has the same problem. The problem was fixed by removing the border shorthand property and replacing it with border-style and border-width.

Here is my code before, NOT working:

```
 .borderWrap{

    border: solid 34px transparent;
    border-image: url(../images/spriteOneFrame.png) 34 34 round;
 }
```

And the new code working:

```
.borderWrap{

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 34px;
    border-image: url(../images/spriteOneFrame.png) 34 34 round;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found that it's obviously the "transparent" property which makes the border not show up in Safari. Changing it to "inherit" made it work.

Comment: Changing color to inherit did not work for me either. But adding a light transparent color did rgba(0,0,0,0.01). But there needs to be an alpha value larger than 0.

Comment: @dardub that worked for me. Maybe you should suggest that as an answer. You definitley have my vote.

Comment: @not2savvy That worked for me in combination with this answer cheers.

Answer (score 5):

In Safari Version 10.1.1 no border-image is displayed at w3schools.com now in June 2017. There is a border-image-generator at border-image dot com (I hope, I am allowed to mention this here!), that works great at least for Safari, chrome an ff for mac.
My example:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
-moz-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
border-image: url(border.png) 27 fill repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking this using the latest version of Safari?
Safari didn't support border-image in versions before 5. Honestly though it would be best to add support to as many older browsers as possible by using the -o, -webkit and -moz tags.
You can find out how to use these tags on the w3schools border-image page.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Generally speaking you just need to add the per browser prefix to the standard css code.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to get the border-image working properly.  It's not supported well enough.  So I changed it in to a background image and got that working fine.

This works in all but Safari and some devices:

```
.rooms {
    color: #fff;
    background: url("../images/paint-blk2.png") 0 0 / 100% 100% no-repeat;
    padding: 25px;
    height:410px;
}
```

But for it so work in Safari it needs to be this:

```
.rooms {
    color: #fff;
    background: url("../images/paint-blk2.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    height:410px;
}
```

Moral of the story, stick with what works until they've perfected the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transparent, or inherit, I used just a random colour and it worked on safari.

The border-image just overrode the image I set. I would still use a good fallback colour in case the border-image doesn't show on older browsers.

```
border: 10px solid blue !important;
border-image: url(/myImage.png) 20% stretch;
```